# Missing "Download offline speech recognition" Setting Option on Nexus 9 Lolipop

Tags: settings, voice-recognition, voice-command, nexus-9

I have a problem, like the title say I don't have the option in my voice setting "Download offline speech recognition". I decided to post it here because I don't find anything in internet after many hours, and I need this functionality for my application.

My device is an HTC Nexus 9 running Lollipop 5.1.1

You can see the problem on this screenshot.

[image: Missing option Download offline speech recognition in voice setting]

<sub>Screenshot of Missing option Download offline speech recognition in voice setting- (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the offline speech recognition is not on Google Settings (usually on `Google Settings - Search & Now - Voice`), but on device Settings:

1. Open device **Settings**
2. Go to **Personal**
3. Go to **Speech**
4. Select **Voice Search**
5. Locate **Download offline speech recognition**

Reference: [Menu tree: Google Nexus 9](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-17914)

Comment: Thank you for you answer Andrew,  but the screenshot in my post is on this location,  and no Locate Download offline speech recognition option is visible :-/

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any hint either...